# Make post request when user is online otherwise store in local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, navigator

On click to submit button, I would like to make a post request when the user is online. if the user is offline I would like to store submitted data in local storage. Unfortunately, I am getting  500 error when clicking on submit button after turning my wifi off. It works when I go offline from the browser network

```
onSubmit() {  
 let postData = [];
for (var groupId in this.deltasByGroupId) {
  if (!this.deltasByGroupId.hasOwnProperty(groupId)) { continue }

  for (var k in this.deltasByGroupId[groupId]) {
    if (!this.deltasByGroupId[groupId].hasOwnProperty(k)) { continue }

    let secs = this.deltasByGroupId[groupId][k];

    var item1 = secs["items"]
    for (var j in item1) {

      var item2 = item1[j]
      for (var l in item2) {

        var listItem = item2["items"]
        for (var li in listItem) {
          this.model = new MeasurementChange(listItem[li].id, listItem[li].percent_complete);
          postData.push(this.model);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
if(navigator.onLine){
  this.pEntryService.postEntries(postData).subscribe(res => {
        alert("Data submitted successfully")
      })

} else{

this.storage.set('cashedData', postData).then(res => {
alert("Data successsfully stored locally")
})
}
}
```

Comment: Then you should check the submitted data and the server-side code why it throws an _"internal server error"_

Comment: The error 500 is a server error, so the value of navigator.onLine is true. If not, can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: @AdamFoerster it works when I go offline from browser network but doesn't work when I turn my wifi off

Comment: `navigator.onLine` is not reliable, it works differently depending on browser. You really should rely on the on the request failing and react accordingly.